# How to make this expressions dynamic?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to make the following expression dynamic with respect to size:

`localparam MAX_ALLOWED_RD     = 32'b1 << WIDTH_min;`

The problem here is that if WIDTH_min becomes 32, the param becomes 0. What I'm trying to replace 32`b1 with something similar to "sizeof (WIDTH_min)"

How do I write this in SystemVerilog?

I have tried the following but get "'A_SIZE' is not a constant"

logic [WIDTH_min : 0] A_SIZE  = 'b1;
localparam MAX_ALLOWED_RD     = A_SIZE << WIDTH_min ;

Comment: Changed logic A_SIZE [WIDTH_min : 0] to  logic [WIDTH_min : 0] A_SIZE. this removes the unpacked error but the other error still remains

Comment: MAX_ALLOWED_RD is used elsewhere in code as (if (MAX_ALLOWED_RD >= MAX_ALLOWED_WR) begin: ..... end)

Comment: localparams are constants. Variables cannot be used in constant expressions. So, A_SIZE cannot be used to make a localparam. There is no way to make a constant *dynamic*. What are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the localparam is, by default, an integer, so its width is 32 bit [31:0].

So when you do this assignment:

```
 localparam MAX_ALLOWED_RD     = 32'b1 << WIDTH_min;
```

you would need 33 bits to assign that.
You could solve this by using the width as parameter:

```
localparam WIDTH_min = 33;
localparam [WIDTH_min:0] MAX_ALLOWED_RD     = 32'b1 << WIDTH_min;
```

A_SIZE must be a parameter or localparam, not logic array.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by doing the following:

```
localparam [WIDTH_min : 0]  WIDTH_min_size = '1;
localparam MAX_ALLOWED_RD     = WIDTH_min_size << ID_WIDTH_min ;
```

(I probably should have framed the question better.)